# Why do we need Upcasting & Downcasting in C#?

Tags: c#, downcast, upcasting

Consider we are having three classes, Shape which is the base class and two other classes Circle and Text that inherits from the base classe (Shape)

Shape.cs

```
namespace ObjectOriented
{
    public class Shape
    {
        public int Height { get; set; }
        public int Width { get; set; }
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }

        public void Draw()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Text.cs

```
using System;

namespace ObjectOriented
{
    public class Text : Shape
    {
        public string FontType { get; set; }
        public int FontSize { get; set; }

        public void Weirdo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Weird stuff");
        }

    }
}
```

Circle.cs

```
namespace ObjectOriented
{
    public class Circle : Shape
    {

    }
}
```

we all know that Upcasting always succeed and that we create a reference to a base class from a subclass reference

```
Text txt = new Text();
Shape shape = txt //upcast
```

and downcasting may throw and **InvalidCastException** for example

```
Text txt = new Text();
Shape shape = txt; //upcast
Circle c = (Circle)shape; //DownCast InvalidCastException
```

what i'm confused about is that what are the **situations/cases** that we might need to up/down cast and object ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally you use upcasting for objects that are stored in, for example, a list. *(shared base type, even `Object` could be used)*

```
List<Shape> shapes = new List<Shape>();

shapes.Add((Shape)new Text());    // <-- the upcast is done automatically
shapes.Add(new Circle());
```

When downcasting, you need to check if it's the right type:

```
foreach(Shape shape in shapes)
{
    if(shape is Circle)
    {
        Circle circle = (Circle)shape;
        // do something..
    }

}
```

One thing is, `Circle` and `Text` are both `Shape`, but you cannot cast a `Circle` to a `Text`. This is because both classes are extending the `Shape` class and adds different functionality/properties.

For example: A `Car` and a `Bike` share their same base `Vihicle` *(a thing used for transporting people or goods, especially on land)*, but a `Bike` extends the `Vihicle` with a saddle and a `Car` extends the vihicle with, for example, a motor. Therefor they cannot be 'casted' to each other, but both can be seen as a `Vihicle`.

---

There are usefull extension methods for this, which handles the type check:

```
foreach(Circle circle in shapes.OfType<Circle>())
{
    // only shapes of type Circle are iterated.
}
```

---

**'Real world' example:**

If you have a Window, there are many controls on it. Like Labels/Buttons/ListViews/etc. All these controls are stored in a collection of their base types.

For example WPF controls: All child controls *(in a FrameWorkElement)* are stored in a `UIElementCollection`. So all controls added as child **must** be derived from `UIElement`.

When you are iterating all child controls, *(UIElement's)* and searching for example a Label, you'll have to check it's type:

```
foreach(UIElement element in this.Children)
{
    if(element is Label)
    {
        Label myLabel = (Label)element;
        myLabel.Content = "Hi there!";
    }
}
```

This loop will change all labels *(within this)* to 'Hi there!'.

Comment: Would you like to mention real world examples for using upcasting & downcasting ? Thank you

Comment: Nice answer. Well written.